# Python Overflow while trying to code the RSA cryptosystem

Tags: python, rsa, overflow

I'm trying to code the cryptosystem RSA for school and i have an overflow problem.

[It is happening when i'm trying to decode de message by doing (m^d)%n.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/299IX.png)

Comment: Use the [3-argument form of the builtin `pow` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.